# Initialize property in Kotlin so that the code is executed only once

Tags: android, kotlin

I would like to know if there is a more idiomatic way of writing the following in Kotlin:

```
private var loadingFlag: Boolean = false

override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        if (!loadingFlag) {
            // do something
            loadingFlag = true
        }
    }
```

so far the closest I could come up with is:

```
val lazyValue: Unit by lazy {
    println("computed!")
    Unit
}

fun main() {
    println(lazyValue)
    println(lazyValue)
}
```

which executes `println("computed!")` only once as expected.

Basically when I call the code I want `println("computed!")` to be called only once and subsequent calls do nothing. Any ideas?

Comment: Why is this not idiomatic? Looks perfectly fine to me.

Comment: why dont you use the singleton?

Comment: Actually the code is executing only once. Then you are only printing the stored value. What is your problem here?

Comment: I apologize, probably my question wasn't clear enough, so I updated it

Comment: @bvk256 Seems to me that the use of `lazy` is a good fit here, and perfectly idiomatic Kotlin.

Comment: @marstran yes, I see that it is possible to omit "Unit" in the code and make it fit within 3 lines, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't consider it idiomatic to have a property with value Unit , or to call a property for its side effect. Those are both code smells.

You can write a custom getter for a Boolean property so it always returns false after the first time it's retrieved. It can be reset by setting it to true.

```
var firstTime: Boolean = true
    get() = field.also { field = false }
```

This is just convenience. There's nothing non-idiomatic about your first block of code.